# Lat and Lon coordinates with 7 digit precision in Java from JSON data

Tags: java, json, double, latitude-longitude, precision

I need to work with lat/lon coordinates, like this: 12.4840299,41.8506791; with a precision of 7 digits, for indoor environment.

But when I extract it from a JSON and I make a Double in this manner:

```
lat = Double.parseDouble(tmp.getString(0));
lon = Double.parseDouble(tmp.getString(1));
```

I obtain this result (tmp is a JSONObject that contain lat/lon):
lat=12.484046 lon=41.85063;
with a precision of only 5/6 digit.

How can I extract all the complete lat/lon from the JSON, with maximum precision?

Thank in advance.

SOLVED: Is a library that I used that truncate the value.

Comment: Um, 12.484046 has 8 digits of precision, and 41.85063 has 7 digits of precision... however, I suspect that it's just a matter of how you're seeing the result.

Comment: I would use `BigDecimal` here or multiply everything by 1e7

Comment: The conversion from `String` to `double` works just fine for the values you provide. The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: In particular, `System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("12.4840299"));` prints out `12.4840299` for me...

Comment: `double` has 15 digits of precision.  (And are you sure you should be parsing your own values?  What does the JSON look like.)

Comment: (Do keep in mind that NSLog and the debugger will display "rounded" floating point values -- basically rounding when the number is within one ULP of a shorter one, and rarely showing more than 6 fraction digits in any case.  The actual number is correct.)

Comment: Here, there is a static JSON that I used for developing. https://gist.github.com/paolodirollo/9834808#file-percorso_statico

Comment: Decimal rounding will not work well with `double`s anyway. If you use Jackson you can configure it so that it deserializes JSON decimal numbers with `BigDecimal`s instead (`USE_BIGDECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS`)

Comment: The numbers in that JSON will be converted (by default) into `double` by most JSON kits.  `double` can handle just shy of 16 digits, and your JSON contains at most 9, so the numbers will be represented to their full precision.  But note that the numbers may *appear* different when logged, since, depending on the logging tool, different precisions may be used.